# How to split one column into two based on a certain character?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I'm looking to split one column in a dataset into 2 columns, whilst still preserving all other columns/data in the dataset.

For example my data looks like (... resprenting many more columns, the dataset is very large):

```
Gene   qval    ...  Chromosome Position
ACE    0.3748  ...    1:234689650
NOS    0.2     ...    2:374896578
BRCA   0.345   ...    12:897655323
```

I want to divide the chromosome position column based on the `:` in the chromosome position to become:

```
Gene   qval    ...   Chromosome    Position
ACE    0.3748  ...    1            234689650
NOS    0.2     ...    2            374896578
BRCA   0.345   ...    12           897655323
```

Currently what I've tried seems either not make a new column or to disrupt the rest of the dataset so it gets jumbled/out of place plus made the first `Chromsome` column appear with its singular chromosome numbers, but the larger `Position` number (the second column I'm trying to create) disappears.

For example I've tried 3 ways:

```
awk 'sub(/\:/," "){$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" file1.txt > file2.txt #displaces columns and removes position column

tr ':' $' ' < file1.txt > file2.txt  #removes : but doesn't divide into 2 columns

sed 's/:/ /g' < file1.txt > file2.txt  #removes : but doesn't divide into 2 columns
```

I've tried code like this based on similar questions, but most questions want to cut one column in half and move the bottom half into a new column, as opposed to having a dividing character split one column.

My data is in a tab delimited file. I'm new to linux, so probably wrong, but is it that for my `sed`  or `tr` code they also need a command stating the split is complete when considering the space newly placed between the numbers as a tab delimited, therefore making them be considered new columns?

Comment: Is the `Chromosome Position` field the only one that may contain a `:` ?

Answer (score 3):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```bsh
mlr --tsv nest --explode --values --across-fields --nested-fs ":" -f "Chromosome Position" \
then rename "Chromosome Position_1",Chromosome,"Chromosome Position_2",Position input.tsv >output.tsv
```

you will have

```
+------+--------+------------+-----------+
| Gene | qval   | Chromosome | Position  |
+------+--------+------------+-----------+
| ACE  | 0.3748 | 1          | 234689650 |
| NOS  | 0.2    | 2          | 374896578 |
| BRCA | 0.345  | 12         | 897655323 |
+------+--------+------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is tab-delimited, then replace colon with tab:

```bsh
tr : $'\t' < file
```

That uses bash's [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with your first approach (excapt that you replace the colon with a space in lieu of a `<TAB>`)? Try an adaption:

```
awk '{sub (/:/, OFS)} 1' OFS="\t" file
```